# Why doesn't my pop up blocker block alert(), confirm(), and prompt()?

Tags: google-chrome, dialog

I was recently looking at ["documentation"](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_confirm2) at W3Schools for window.confirm() and after doing the "Try it" and watching the dialog box pop up, I wondered my AdBlock doesn't block this.  Also, I was using my Chrome mobile browser, which also has pop-ups set to "blocked" in the settings. If my browser, doesn't block dialog boxes such as alert(), confirm(), and prompt(), what is it blocking?

Comment: AdBlock blocks popup ads(small new window ads) and ads on pages like banners etc. Alert confirm prompt are not considered as ads, so they are not blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing: avoid w3schools.

Second: I think you answered your own question.  Those are dialog boxes that you are seeing, not ads or pop-ups.  Adblockers are for blocking iframes and new browser windows.  Dialog boxes aren't either of those things.  They are basic browser functions, so Adblocker won't disrupt that behavior.

Comment: Thank you. Yea, I typically avoid w3schools, hence the "documentation" in quotes, but I knew they usually have a "try it" and I wanted to see if the confirm dialog would pop-up in my browser.  I never made the distinction between dialog boxes, iframes, and new browser windows, though. Good stuff.